# Reorder lines in a file

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to reorder the lines in a file:

I have a file with some atom coordinates, each atom in a line, and I need some atoms to be written before others. Let's say:

```
atom c1
atom c2
atom c3
```

I need to reorder the lines. Something like:

```
atom c2
atom c1
atom c3
```

Is there any way to do so without a list?

Even creating a list, I didn't succeed. last trial was:

```
i = open("input.pdb", "r")
o = open("output.pdb", "w")
l = []
for line in i:
    l. append(line.split())
    for line in l:
        if "atom c2" in line:
        a = l.index(line)
        b = int(a) -1
        l[a] = l[b]
for line in l:
    0.write("{}\n".format(line))
o.close()
os.remove("input.pdb")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post the entire homework assignment exercise

Comment: `0.write` ? Did you mean `o.write`?

Comment: If this is the way your code is indented the `if "atom c2" in line:` block is empty and all the code after it will always execute.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, since you give no other indication, that you know in advance what order the lines should be written in.

```
atom c1    # line 0
atom c2    # line 1
atom c3    # line 2
```

In your example, that would be `1, 0, 2`. Then instead of `for line in l` (also, *please* [never name a variable "`l`"!](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)), you could instead iterate through your list of line indices, and write each corresponding line.

```
with open("input.pdb", "r") as infile:
    lines = [line for line in infile] # Read all input lines into a list

ordering = [1, 0, 2]
with open("output.pdb", "w") as outfile:
    for idx in ordering: # Write output lines in the desired order.
        outfile.write(lines[idx])
```